# Can throwing the iPhone high in the air launch my app or trigger desired function in iOS 7 or later

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, accelerometer

My app is an emergency app. It will be used by people in emergency and disasters.
It's possible that they got stuck in situations where they just don't have the time to enter or draw their password on the lock screen, launch the app and push a button. Is it possible that my app can ask the OS to launch the app if user throw their iPhone up in the air or shake it vigorously or **something else**.

**What I wish to achieve by this ?**
I want that OS launches my app in background if the user say shake his/her iPhone vigorously. Once launched my app will make a network request and keep running in background for short time.

PS:I think it's possible with the accelerometer.

Comment: Do you really want to throw your phone in the air and risk dropping and breaking it? If you're in a disaster situation, a working phone is quite important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accelerometer will not work because Apple doesn't allow background processes opening apps. In your case, user must be opening the app by himself/herself manually. (PS. As far as I know, it's possible in Android)

Comment: Can you be specific. I mean why can't we use accelerometer

Comment: Accelerometer will not work because Apple doesn't allow background processes opening apps. In your case, user must be opening the app by himself/herself manually. (PS. As far as I know, it's possible in Android)

Comment: I know about an app that can be trigerred by hitting the power button twice. Do, you know how to achieve that. Also, can I put a button on lock screen that if pushed launches my app in background. I just want to make it accessible very quickly

Comment: What is the name of that app?

Comment: Thanks! I don't even have iOS device to do that

Comment: Please tell me how it worked and if you have any idea how it worked

Comment: Hi, the app is available only in India store and I can't install it. Hovewer, I read their specs from iTunes. As far as I understood, this app also hasn't got a feature like opening with accelerometer or opening directly from main/lock screen. Even in their specs, they mentioned it as "To alert the guardians, activate the app and then press the panic button"...

Answer (score 1):

iOS background tasking problems aside:

Apple don't allow apps that encourage the user to do things that might damage their iOS device. So your 'throw in the air' idea is out.

As for shaking the device -- this just isn't practical. What if the device gets shaken by accident? You've then got false alarms to deal with.

The crux of the issue is that something that triggers an emergency response should be a deliberate action which is hard to do trigger by accident.

Comment: Can you confirm this statement that "it's not possible to register motion gestures with iOS that can launch the app if it's not running. "

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can't launch an app based on motion gestures.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work - and here's why.

Your app would need to run in background to handle motion events. Apps running in background can get killed at any time, i.e. if memory gets low. There might be some restrictions about running and and resource usage as well.

An app in the background cannot bring itself to the front.

Launching from a locked screen would bring great security risks.

Throwing into the air seems like a gesture that can easily be triggered by accident.

I must admit that I'm pretty happy that those apps are not allowed on the AppStore - as it would open many doors that I'd like to see kept close.

Comment: Thanks! I am sorry if you just read my previous comment. I was just frustrated by the comments of people. Everyone was just laughing at me. Also, as your answer say it's not possible to register motion gestures with iOS that can launch the app  if it's not running.
Again I am sorry if you read my previous comment.

Comment: All good - didn't read it. :) Bottom line - cannot use iPhone as emergency device for use with boxer gloves.